# Tk constructor gives segmentation fault

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm running Python 3.10.4 on Ubuntu 22.04. When I call the `Tk` constructor from the `tkinter` package, I get a segmentation fault. I wrote a minimal script to reproduce the error:

```
import tkinter as tk

print("Creating GUI")
gui = tk.Tk()
print("Done!")
```

and here's what it looks like when I run it:

```
malin@addition:~/tmp$ python3 tktest.py 
Creating GUI
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
malin@addition:~/tmp$
```

Does anybody know what's the problem, or if there is a workaround?

Comment: do you run it on computer with XWindows (graphics environment)? `tkinter` may not work when you run on server without graphics environment because it may not have installed `tk/tcl` and it has not graphics environment to display windows

Comment: Yes, I run it in a graphics environment. Since python does not complain on the import, I guess we can be pretty sure that `tk/tcl` is installed.

Comment: I may also mention that it worked fine before software updater ran the last update.

Comment: it only shows that sometimes it is better to use little older version because the newest version may have some mistake

Comment: I used Python3.12. Worked for me.

Comment: Yes, I also got around it by upgrading Python.